# Art project using SMD LEDs and resistors

Tags: led, resistors

I am trying to light a sculpture from the inside with an SMD LED and resistor due to space limitations. I am ready to do some tiny soldering, but can't find the right resistor.

The calculator tells me 1/8w at 0.8 Ω. The smallest SMD resistors I see are 1 kΩ. The resistance look super high, am I reading something wrong? Will a larger or smaller resistor protect the LED better?

I plan to use 2 AAA batteries and 125 lumen LEDs (links below). I would like to connect them with enameled magnet wire.

[image: Resister Calculation]

[LED SMD link](https://www.ledsupply.com/closeout/luxeon-r-neutral-white-led-emitter)

[Link to resistor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08QRP3N51)

Comment: Your math is correct. The internal output impedance of the batteries is at least 0.8 ohms so you could skip the resistor altogether. But 350mA is a lot of current for AA batteries - they won't last long.

Comment: Your plan to use only 2 AAA cells is not going to work very well or for very long. If you look up some discharge curves for AAA alkaline batteries ([example](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Typical-discharge-curves-and-available-energy-for-alkaline-AAA-batteries-3_fig3_221926555)), you'll see that although they start at 1.5V that voltage starts dropping pretty quickly. For this application you'll have much greater success using a 3.7V lithium cell.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: These LEDs need to be mounted on a heatsink. They will very quickly burn out when used at full power without one. If you really need that much brightness, you'll have to engineer some kind of cooling solution.

Comment: @DamienD Thanks I am going to get a different bulb at150 mA. Less of a headache! The other might be overkill.

Comment: @brhans Thanks, Good to know. Gonna switch the bulb...

Comment: Do you have room for more batteries? Since your 3D-Printed PLU sculpture melts at 205° F, does it have ventilation? You can avoid heat build-up in your sculpture by using light-pipe or fiber optics to bring the light in. If all else fails, this might work:  [LED Fairy String Lights, 10Ft/3M 30-Leds, needs 3xAA](https://www.amazon.com/ANJAYLIA-Festival-Decorations-Crafting-Operated/dp/B01EWBC55A). (full disclosure-no affiliation/profit). Finally, have you considered the [Joule-Thief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_thief) using one AAA (or 1 AA) into one of your LED's?

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD, did not see this comment of yours for a while. Has a small hole for vent. I did go with this lower mA so should not overheat. [LED I got](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01CUGACUO?ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details)  I do Have those mini string lights though. Didn't think they were bright enough, but may try them again now that you mentioned it.

Answer (score 3):

These are [obsolete LEDs](https://lumileds.com/wp-content/uploads/files/DS101.pdf), and require a very large heat sink in comparison to the LED.

Lumileds [AB32](https://lumileds.com/wp-content/uploads/files/AB32.pdf) has some detailed information on the pads that are required to get near to maximum brightness, however they are assuming something like an aluminum core PCB of large size to carry all the heat away. At 350mA that tiny chip will be dissipating the majority of a watt (input power of about 1 watt, with some leaving as light).

That's a great deal of power for a 3 x 4.5mm SMT part. Without a large heat sink it will start to degrade in seconds.

Maybe you can get enough light for your application at a more reasonable current, in which case the resistor calculations might make more sense too. You can play with it if you have some to sacrifice. Start at 20mA or something like that with a resistor and a bench power supply. Maybe you can figure out a way to draw heat out (attach it to an aluminum or copper plate, bar or rod, for example) and still get the effect you desire.

Comment: Thanks SP. good advise. Would a plate be more efficient than a premade heat sink (oversized). I like the plate though.
Could I be making too much effort for obsolete technology?

Comment: @Jerny Probably not much difference for obsolete unless you need factory support or need to buy more of them. Newer designs in the same package may or may not be still available, I didn't look. Newer ones might be *slightly* more efficient, but doubtful it would make any difference to you. As far as heat sink- I (and we) have no idea what your constraints are. If it's a super bright light at the tip of a flexible insect antenna then it would be a problem. If you've got a 2 x 3" 3mm thick aluminum plate the problem reduces to coupling the back of the LED to the plate and not shorting it out.

Comment: @Sphero OK fair enough. I guess I have some testing to do. Would thermal glue help to prevent a short maybe? would you know a good site for the resistors? I am having trouble finding ones with less than 1 ohm... Thanks!

Comment: Things that conduct heat well tend to conduct electricity. Personally I would design a single-layer aluminum core PCB and have it made, but that would take a bit longer right now because of Spring Festival. Check suppliers like Digikey, Mouser for resistors  if you're in the USofA. You don't yet know enough to pick a value though.

Comment: @Sphero thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Going higher in resistance will just lead to less current and therefor less brightness, so nothing bad will happen.

Your average AAA battery has a few hundred mΩ of series resistance "built in" (ESR), so to get to 350 mA, you may need less than 800 mΩ on your resistor.

Moreover, at 350 mA though a 800 mΩ resistor, it will burn 98 mW, close to the specified 1/8 W, so it will run very hot (>100 degrees C). Try finding a physically larger one or use several in series or parallel to spread out the heat.

Do you really need to run the LED at full specific current for your application?

Comment: In terms of overheating the resistor is the least concern when the LED itself will be dissipating the better part of one watt.

Comment: @DamienD I was hoping it would come on a heatsink, but I’ve been wrong before.

Comment: Thanks W, I don't need to run it at full specs, It will be inside a 3d print so heat will be an issue. I don't want to melt the PLU (melts at 205 F) or worse burn it. The 125 lumen may be high, but I can't tell until I put it in. 
So I guess a larger one would  be good to start. Would the LED just be dimmer? could you suggest a good site to get a few? thanks

Comment: @Jenny For reference, an incandescent 60 W light bulb is 806 lumen in the US and 730 lumen in Europe so 125 lumen is enough to brightly illuminate a small area or dimly an entire room. Purchase recommendations are off topic on this site, but your favorite vendor (Digi-Key, Mouser, RS, Farnell or similar) will have plenty of LEDs in stock with proper datasheets to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this LED will exhaust your batteries very quickly because it may take much more than 350mA with just a resistor or no resistor as a regulator.
[I advise this type of LED][1] (the led, not the brand). Here is a link found at random.
You can also try 5060 or 5070 or 3535 SMD LEDs, usualy 150 mA. They may be less powerful  but enough for what you want to do and more suitable for a battery powered circuit.

It's not crazy to use 1K ohm resistors with LEDs of relatively low power (Less than 0.25A). You can play with two or more resistors in parallel to tune the current. With more power, resistors should ne avoided because of heat (power dissipation) and then, an exact voltage or a constant current power supply used.

If it's for permanent or semi-permanent lighting, and there is a wall outlet nearby, you should use a small power supply. It will cost less than replacing batteries.
If you take a 5V power supply, you can put two of these LEDs in series without any resistor.
[1]: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004026907958.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.main.25.63949c59YT2Ecr&algo_pvid=fc20a532-cc4a-4033-abf2-ed3b016f3e54&aem_p4p_detail=2024021515542113020093037477980005875892&algo_exp_id=fc20a532-cc4a-4033-abf2-ed3b016f3e54-12&pdp_npi=4%40dis%21EUR%210.61%210.61%21%21%210.64%210.64%21%40210318e817080412613938630ec6d3%2112000027789264604%21sea%21LT%21861709977%21AC&curPageLogUid=CGivVeCdn87I&utparam-url=scene%3Asearch%7Cquery_from%3A&search_p4p_id=2024021515542113020093037477980005875892_13

Comment: Yes I am getting that idea... I really don't know what to expect in terms of Lumen and how bright they are. Maybe I was over zealous...
I do need it on battery power. So I will aim at 150mA. And but accordingly in the future.
I did buy the LED's in my initial link already. Can I lower it to 150mA with a resistor? Not sure how I would figure out which one if so.

Comment: get an LED flashlight and do some experiments to determine how much light you need and if the batteries will last long enough,

Comment: @Jerny Yes you can lower it to 150mA with a resistor. Or with a potentiometer that will allow to regulate the light. (Make sure it supports enough mA. ) I'm not sure how it will react with only 150mA, but it costs nothing to try.

Comment: @JasenСлаваУкраїні  May sound dumb, but, how do you figure out what LED is being used?

Comment: Many manufacturers will tell you in the advertising material, also just measuring the power consumption can give a lot of information.